# Django Rest Framework API by accept multiple input and output multiple data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am two months with Django and API Rest Framework.
I am developing an API to accept (userid and week_number), and output with (week_number and status).

This is my model:

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    week_number = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This is my complete data example:

```
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "userid": 1,
        "week_number": "32",
        "status": "completed"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "userid": 1,
        "week_number": "33",
        "status": "approved"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "userid": 1,
        "week_number": "34",
        "status": "incomplete"
    }
]
```

API I want is like this:

```
ACCEPT: userid=1
ACCEPT: week_number=33
ACCEPT: week_number=34
OUTPUT: week_number=33,status="approved"
OUTPUT: week_number=34,status="incomplete"
```

Note: I do not want data about `week_number=32`

I not sure how to code for this kind of API. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Hi Chan, do you wish to have separate calls for each week_number or are you saying you want to make one call with user_id and a list of week_numbers and get results based on that??

Comment: i wish to have any type of tutorial regardless separate call or single call, as long as i get the result. I will appreciate for both methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the general route to getting what you want.

in models.py

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    week_number = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

in serializer.py:

```
class TimesheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Timesheet
        // specify the fields that you want API to return below
        fields = ('week_number', 'status')
```

in views.py:

```
from rest_framework import generics    

class TimesheetListView(generics.ListAPIView):
        serializer_class = TimesheetSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
            //get user and week_number from GET request
            user = self.request.GET['user']
            week_number = self.request.GET['week']

            //filter and return the first result where user=user and week=week
            return Timesheet.objects.filter(user=user, week_number=week_number)
```

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^api/timesheet$', views.TimesheetListView.as_view(), name='timesheet'),
```

you can then access this endpoint with e.g.:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/timesheet?user=123&week=33&format=api

It's good practice to disable Browsable API in production. it can be done by the following code in settings.py(this way you won't have to use &format=api in your call above):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    other settings ...
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
    other settings ...
}
```

and in development mode you can do in settings.py:

```
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
)
```

I didn't get the time to test this but this is the general guidelines of achieving what you want. Do add the required exception-handling to this as well. 
you should go through the Django DRF tutorial though if you haven't already: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: I got an error: NameError: name 'generics' is not defined. Then, i added "from rest_framework import generics". Next i got an error: "name 'TimesheetListView' is not defined", caused by urls.py. Can I know how to solve the second error? @sarosh

Comment: Second error I solved by amending to : url(r'^api/timesheet$', views.TimesheetListView.as_view(), name='timesheet'),..... and I accessing endpoint with http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/timesheet?format=api&user=1&week=32 . However, I got 
I removed .first() in views.py so that the API fetch the result i want.
Problem solved.
Thanks @Sarosh

Comment: Hi, glad to be of help. i've added the changes you made to the answer. Also, in production you usually want to disable Browsable API. i've also added the code to enable and disable the browsable API in the edit. this way you won't have to enter ?format=api to your calls